# Serving static html behind authentication without routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, auth0

I am currently serving public pages with:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

I want to have release folder inside it behind auth0 authentication.

```
app.use(authenticate, express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public', 'release')))
```

To make this work, the client would have to send an access token when accessing server/release. Is there a way to inject this token in the request header without having to set a component that adds it and then has to handle the static HTML response and render its content?

Basically, I am trying to avoid having to set routes, component to add the header, send a request, display static HTML content response.

Let me know if I am not clear and I'll try to clarify a bit better.